# cannot find class name component in app.module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, class, web

***"courses.components.ts"***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: '<h2>Courses</h2>'
})
export class CoursesComponent {
    }
```

***"app.module.ts"***

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CoursesComponent  //error
  ]
})
```

[app.modile.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utq6N.png) & [component.ts files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTJM6.png)

Comment: Did you import `CoursesComponent` correctly in `app.module.ts`?

Comment: Fixed your links. The answer is in the first image. You did not import it so how could it be available?

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks it worked. i'm new to this, where i'm learning from they show auto-import plugin which automatically import component but in my case it's not importing automatically. can you help me out with this?

Comment: I cannot tell you why a plugin would not work but I can help you by providing serious advice: _A plugin is not a substitute for understanding how the language works and until you understand the fundamentals, and this is a fundamental, you probably should not be using such a plugin at all._